# RH implies prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

I have heard that it is easy to show the prime number theorem using the Riemann hypothesis (RH implies PNT). I have also heard that the prime number theorem is equivalent to the (shown) fact that the zeros of $\zeta$ lie outside of $\text{Re}(z) = 1$.

This is very interesting, but I can't seem to find a proof, let alone the nicest one. Maybe someone has a link?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_for_L-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02301.pdf
and
https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf
about Riemann's original paper.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know anything about an analogue for finite fields?

Comment: Sorry, no. I have never thought about it. And a field has no primes.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer it was just what I wanted. p.s. the analogy is $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ ($\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ are both Euclidian domains, and their fraction field has a single discrete valuation). I was being cavalier.

Comment: Interesting idea. But the zeta function is so deeply connected to complex numbers, that I have difficulties imagining a version over an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p(x).$

Comment: @MariusS.L. there is a very rich theory of zeta functions over finite fields; see [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/~dwan/gottingen.pdf) for instance